# Divergence between two random variables

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, gaussian

I have two Gaussian random variables $X$ and $Y$, each of which is an estimator of an underlying quantity. I need to measure whether $Y$ is estimating something different than $X$. So if the mean of $Y$ is very different to the mean of $X$, that is good. However, if the variance of $Y$ is also much higher than the variance of $X$ it might just be that $Y$ is a poor estimator and the different mean is not meaningful (if you'll excuse the pun).

So for a fixed $X$, I need a function of $Y$ that increases with $\left|\mu_Y-\mu_X\right|$ but that decreases with $\sigma_Y$ (and is zero if and only if $\sigma_Y = \sigma_X$ and $\mu_Y = \mu_X$). I don't really know whether to call this a measure, a divergence or something else, since it will be negative when $\mu_Y = \mu_X$ and $\sigma_Y > \sigma_X$.

I thought that the Kullback-Leibler divergence might be the way to go but it responds the wrong way to changes in the variance of $Y$. Also, it can't be negative.

Clearly, something like $\left|\mu_Y-\mu_X\right| + \sigma_X - \sigma_Y$ has the above properties but I'm looking for something a little more grounded in information theory.

Ideally, this would generalize to distributions other than Gaussian.

Comment: Could you explain why KL-divergence is not suitable in a bit more detail? 

Comment: Your "if and only if" statement can't work if your "divergence" $f$ is a continuous function: every curve from a point where $f > 0$ to a point where $f < 0$ must intersect the set where $f = 0$.

Comment: VSJ: KL-divergence would think that a $Y$ with a large variance was very different to $X$. I want something that penalizes variance.

Robert: Yes, of course. I should have said something "is zero if $X = Y$". That is all I really wanted and I do want $f$ to be continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0<\alpha<1$ (typically $\alpha=0.05$) and choose $\varepsilon>0$ such that

$$\alpha = \mathbb P(\left |X-\mu_X\right | > \varepsilon)$$

Now let

$$f = \mathbb P(\left |Y-\mu_X\right | > \varepsilon) - \alpha$$

Then

1. $f$ is increasing with $|\mu_X-\mu_Y|$,
2. $f$ is decreasing with $\sigma_Y$, and
3. $f=0$ when $\mu_X=\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_X=\sigma_Y$.

This approach comes not so much from information theory as from hypothesis testing, in particular the notion of [statistical power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power). Some generalizing from the case of the normal distribution seems possible, but note that in (3) we need the distribution to be determined by $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y$.

Comment: Many thanks Bjørn. I'll definitely give this a try. I've just started reading "Information Theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms" by MacKey which promises to connect information theory and statistical inference. Perhaps I'll have a better understanding of this once I'm done with that.

Comment: Is it possible to consider the entropy of $|Y-\mu_X|>\epsilon$ as some kind of divergence? I mean, it would have an interesting interpretation in terms of such an RV.

Comment: @Nacho hmm, I'm not sure... you may consider formulating it as a Question rather than a Comment so you can add some background on what your goal is.